# shifting arrays with nulls/empty elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've been reading a lot on arrays and questions on here but couldn't find any answer to this.

I have an array which will equal either:

```
Toys[][] toys = { {toy, toy, toy, toy}, {toy}, {}, {toy,toy}, {toy} };
```

or

```
Toys[][] toys = { {toy, toy, toy, toy}, {toy}, null, {toy,toy}, {toy} };
```

I'm trying to shift the element(s) after the nulled or empty element to the left so it would equal to this:

```
 Toys[][] toys = { {toy, toy, toy, toy}, {toy}, {toy,toy}, {toy} };
```

I've tried streaming values like this:

```
toys = (Toys[][]) Arrays.stream(toys).filter(i -> !(i == null || i.length == 0)).toArray();
```

but for some reason it does nothing

Comment: Have you thought about using an `ArrayList` instead of a formal 2D array?

Comment: Surely i shouldn't have to go through the trouble of creating a list for this

Comment: Don't know the Stream enought, but this would still be a simple shift, this could be an `Array`, an `int` or any `Object` in the `Array`. If null or empty, shift (using an index), if an other null or empty, shift twice... you get the idea. Of course, I can't write it for you, at least try it yourself ;)

Comment: what if you have a large amount of elements after the null, is there any productive way to shift them instead of creating a new array and individually shifting elements

Comment: Are you sure your code is not throwing an exception?

Comment: Why do you want a new Array ? Unless you really want to reduce the length of the Array at the end (to remove the null at the end) but in that case, using an `ArrayList` would have been smarted ;) you can always count the number of items an then recreate an new array from the first one, this would be a O(n) for both loops (the first to shift and count, the second to rebuild a new array). **EDIT : what shows the debugger here ?**

Comment: that code is literally the executable, it returns exactly what it was given (toys) and doesn't filter a null or empty element, if its any help streaming works for 1d arrays but not 2d

Comment: @JackSmith that can't be "literally the executable" because all code in Java must be defined as part of a class.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is throwing an exception. The zero-argument [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--) method returns `Object[]`, which you're incorrectly casting to `Toys[][]`. Try [this overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) instead:

```
toys = Arrays.stream(toys)
        .filter(i -> !(i == null || i.length == 0))
        .toArray(Toys[][]::new);
```

Comment: it wasn't throwing any exception, but even this way doesn't edit the array at all, don't know what's wrong, it seems to operate fine with 1d arrays, but not with 2ds

Comment: @JackSmith That's the best I can do without a [mcve].

Comment: @JackSmith Here's a simple test demonstrating it works fine: http://ideone.com/US5cZv